# bootstrap grid 1 is too small 2 is too wide

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the problem with bootstrap 3.0.0

I have a grid system that looks like this:

This image is with col-md-2:

[image: This image is with col-md-2]
This image is with col-md-1:

[image: This image is with col-md-1]

So `col-md-2` is too wide and `col-md-1` is too small. I know you can't use `col-md-1.5` so is there any other way to fix this?

Comment: post the code you have for that, it's impossible to tell from an image

Comment: decrease width of container, use margin, text-align, ....  or do not use bootstrap class for this bit and make your own style

Comment: There is nothing you can do outside of overriding or adjusting the predefined column widths.  Also, bootstrap grid system is based on percentages. Unless you have set  a static width somewhere, the column widths will change depending on screen size and resolution.

Comment: I changed the width of class="row" and it worked. Thanks G-Cyr

Answer (score 0):

The comments also suggest this, but the only way you're going to get the appearance you want is if you make a custom rule (or do some inline styling) for the specific element(s).

So keep the style as `col-md-1` or `col-md-2`, whichever is closer to your target size, and then add a custom style with whatever name you want and give it a width/margin/etc. that fits appropriately.

Since I can't see the code I can't tell you exactly what I'd do differently, but personally I'd do all the styling myself (`col` is better for body content alignment anyway) using a combination of the `navbar` and `btn` components to create the navbar, and leave all the alignment work to entirely custom styling.

Hope that helps a bit.